# Simple code to create new directory on physical SD Card

Tags: java, android

Can some one provide me the code to create a new directory on the REMOVABLE PHYSICAL SD CARD for android 5?

Psuedo code below.

```
Button clicked
{
    NewDir=REMOVABLE PHYSICAL SD CARD root + "/newdir"
    MakeDirectory(NewDir)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add permission to manifest write to external storage (on higher versions you need to ask for write external storage permission):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then add this:

```
File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard0/path/to/your/directory");
try{
  if(dir.mkdir()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Directory is not created");
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```